# Edit phone number in phone app

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to edit a manually dialed phone number before re-dialling? Occasionally I have a typo in the number or forgot to add the country code prefix.

The only ways to handle this I know so far is

- write down the number and re-dial, or
- copy the complete number, paste into a notes/text app, edit there, copy again and paste into the phone app.

Not exactly user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you are correct in your assumption, once a number has been typed and a call initiated, it is not able to be edited within the phone app directly, and needs to be either sent to a new contact where you can then amend the number, or cut/paste elsewhere to allow you to make changes.

Comment: Which is a shame IMHO.

Comment: Quite true, I think the idea is that if you use a number more than once, you add a contact.  And if you only use it once then a little finger trouble isn't so bad.

Comment: What a SHAME for a $1000+ phone. I'm gonna sound like a angry boomer but i think it's really ridicolous that i cannot edit the phone number. It does a million thing and yet it's missing a basic feature on what it should do best: being a phone 

Answer (score -1):

I found that using VoIP apps, you can edit a number after copy/pasting into the calling/dialing field, but you cannot do this with the native iPhone app.